# Performance-effective way to transform XML data represented as Writeable

Tags: java, xml, groovy, io

I'm working on utility method that allows conversion of XML data into formatted `String` and before you're going to think it's a trivial task for `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` let me explain the specific constraints I've faced with.

The input data *does not exist* at the moment conversion starts. Actually it's represented as `groovy.lang.Writeable` ([javadoc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Writable.html)) instance that I could output into any `java.io.Writer` instance. Signature of method looks like this:

```
static String serializeToString(Writable source)
```

My current solution involves few steps and actually provides expected result:

1. Create `StringWriter`, output `source` there and convert to `String`
2. Create `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource` instance based on this string (using `StringReader`)
3. Create new `StringWriter` instance and wrap it into `javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult`
4. Perform transformation using instance of `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`
5. Convert `StringWriter` to `String`

While solution does work I'm not pleased enough with its efficiency. This method will be used really often and I do want to optimize it. What I'd like to avoid is necessity to perform multiple conversions along the line:

1. From `Writeable` to `String` (unformatted)
2. From `String` to `StreamSource` (which means that data will be parsed again)
3. From `StreamSource` to `String` again (formatted)

So the question is whether it's possible to build pipe-like flow which eliminates unnecessary conversions?

**UPDATE #1:**

To give a little bit more context, I'm converting `GPathResult` instance to formatted string using `StreamingMarkupBuilder.bindNode()` method which produces `Writable` instance. Unfortunately there is no way to specify `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to produce formatted output.

**UPDATE #2:**

I did experiment with implementation based on PipedWriter + PipedReader but experiments didn't show much speed gain from this approach. Looks like it's not that critical issue in this case.

Comment: Why are you parsing the XML String you just generated?

Comment: Because I want to get formatted output (i.e. with indentation) and Writable output is unformatted string.

Comment: So you want it to be performance efficient and pretty? ;)  Cannot the Writeables be changed to give a pretty format?

Comment: Peter, I agree that prettifying might be harmful for performance but that is my requirement. What I'm trying to avoid is going back and forth with parsing/serializing XML. I've edited post to add some clarity on purpose of this utility method.

Comment: Like I said, if the WRitable produced the pretty output you needed, there would be no need to parse it and you won't have much of a performance hit (other than making the XML larger than it need to be)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to make Writable to produce pretty output. If it was possible I wouldn't need utility method at the first place :)

Comment: Your suggestion may be what you have to live with.  The only other thing I can suggest is writing a simple parser which lookst for `<` and `</` and put the spaces/newlines where you want. However I would time what you have and see where it is spending the most time, as this change might not be the worst of the timings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what you mean exactly by "XML data", but you could think of representing the "Yet-to-be" stuff as a SAXSource directly, thereby by-passing the "to-string" and "parse-string" steps.

Comment: Unfortunately SAXSource is based on InputStream or Reader while I'm starting basically with Writer

Comment: No, SAXSource has a getXMLreader() method. One could possibly arrange it so that the parse() method of the XMLreader starts generating SAX events. Those events would depend directly on the internal structure of the source object(s).

Comment: Per, it's not possible to change the way XML is generate in the first place (please see Update #1 in my post)

Comment: Still, if you have a GPathResult, it seems to me that you should be able to navigate it a and generete SAXEvents. But, I've only briefly reaad the the bare Javadoc.

Comment: Per, after a bit of thinking I think your idea might be helpful. I could implement SAXSource based on Writable instance (not sure if it's easy thing to do). For this +1